# Errors and can't get local ionic project pushed to private github repository

Tags: git, github, repository, push

I have a local ionic project, created a private github repository.

They said to do this:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/shh/TestThis.git
git push -u origin master
```

It is not working this is what I am getting on the command line:

```
SHHs-iMac:testThis shh$ git remote add origin git@github.com:shh/TestThis.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
SHHs-iMac:testThis shh$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/shh/TestThis.git'
```

Nothing is showing up in github and I'm really not sure how to proceed. I followed what I read but am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to guess exactly what is going on, bug the error message

> SHHs-iMac:testThis shh$ git remote add origin git@github.com:shh/TestThis.git
>   fatal: remote origin already exists.

is telling you that you already have a local remote called `origin`, and you are attempting to add a new one with the same name.  To resolve this, type the following:

```
git remote show origin
```

This will show you to which URL your old `origin` is pointing.  If it be already pointing to the place you want on GitHub, then just proceed and use it.  If not, then you can try creating a new remote via:

```
git remote add origin2 https://github.com/shh/TestThis.git
git push -u origin2 master
```

Comment: Thank you, I did this it was in the right place so I proceeded but got the same errors, and can't proceed.

Comment: You created an `origin2` and you still get the same error?  Really?

Comment: I finally got it working, thanks! But not until I had set it to origin3, after doing git remote add origin, origin2. Is there a way to retract what I sent out remotely to origin, origin2, etc. from the command line? 

Probably silly question but if someone else has an app with the same name and since I pushed this code to origin remotely, which then wasn't used in my repository, when they setup their repository by any chance would my code show up or be connected?

Comment: You should be fine except that you now have several local references to the same remote.  Your committed work would normally be clearly identifiable as coming from you at least when using GitHub.  But other users won't know that you had a mess locally, assuming the code you push is OK.

Comment: Thanks again, does it matter that it is a private repository? To be clear, what you are saying is that my code isn't just sitting somewhere on github that I can't see because it was committed but no longer matches my repository's name? And there is no way to reset and clear origins1-3 (4 worked) so that I can use them in the future (what they are pointing to now doesn't exist as I renamed the repository and deleted two). Thanks again!

Comment: Ignore or remove the remote references you don't want (e.g. `origin 1`).  They are all pointing to the same location, so all anyone should see of your branch is what you pushed most recently.

Comment: Thanks but to be clear is there anyway to remove and clear it as origin from the command line or only by deleting it in github?

Comment: `origin2` only exisits within Git, not within GitHub.  To be clear, those extra remote references exist locally on your machine but not on GitHub.  In fact, they were probably all pointing to the same remote.